# nav open active link submenu and maintain on page reload

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="sidebarMenu" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-blue-400 sidebar collapse">
        <div class="position-sticky pt-3 sidebar-sticky" style="width: 190px;">

            <ul class="list-unstyled ps-0">
                <li class="border-top my-3"></li>
                @hasrole('admin')

                <li class="mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-toggle d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded border-0 collapsed"
                            data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#home-collapse" aria-expanded="true">
                        Users
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse show" id="home-collapse">
                        <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                            @can('view users')
                                <li><a href="{{ url('admin/users') }}"
                                       class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded active">Users List</a></li>
                            @endcan
                            @can('add users')
                                <li><a href="{{ url('admin/users/create') }}"
                                       class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">New User</a></li>
                            @endcan
                            <li><a href="{{ url('admin/roles') }}"
                                   class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Roles</a></li>


                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-toggle d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded border-0 collapsed"
                            data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#dashboard-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        Organization<br> Structure
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse" id="dashboard-collapse">
                        <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                            <li><a href="{{ url('admin/faculties') }}"
                                   class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Faculties</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('admin/departments') }}"
                                   class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Departments</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('admin/degreePrograms') }}"
                                   class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Degree Programs</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-toggle d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded border-0 collapsed"
                            data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#orders-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        Semesters
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse" id="orders-collapse">
                        <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                            <li><a href="{{ url('admin/semesters') }}"
                                   class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Semesters</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                @endhasrole
                @hasanyrole('Dean|Thesis Coordinator|GRC member|HoD|GRC Convenior')
                <li class="border-top my-3"></li>
                <li class="mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-toggle d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded border-0 collapsed"
                            data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#academic-users-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        Academic Users
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse" id="academic-users-collapse">
                        <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                            <li><a href="{{ url('academic_users/users') }}"
                                   class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Users List</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>


                @endhasanyrole
                <li class="border-top my-3"></li>
                <li class="mb-1">
                    <button class="btn btn-toggle d-inline-flex align-items-center rounded border-0 collapsed"
                            data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#account-collapse" aria-expanded="false">
                        Account
                    </button>
                    <div class="collapse" id="account-collapse">
                        <ul class="btn-toggle-nav list-unstyled fw-normal pb-1 small">
                            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Profile</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded">Settings</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <form method="POST" id="logout" action="{{ route('logout') }}" x-data>
                                    @csrf
                                    <a href="#" class="link-dark d-inline-flex text-decoration-none rounded"
                                       onclick="logout()">
                                        <i class='bx bx-log-out nav_icon'></i>
                                        <span class="nav_name">Sign out</span>
                                    </a>
                                </form>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Here is my sidebar.
[image: sidebar nav]

I want that when I click on some link like **Faculties** in the image above then **Users** submenu collapse and **Organization Structure** submenu expands and also save its state on page reload.

Currently when I click Faculties link, Faculties page open but Users submenu is expanded and all others are hidden.
[image: Navbar]

Comment: What's your question? You'll need to somehow save the menu state and reapply it. Bootstrap doesn't do that.

Comment: Yes I want to do that and if bootstrap dose not do that is there any other way some library etc...

Comment: Sure there is, but that question is far too broad for SO. Library requests are also off topic.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=active+link+on+page+reload+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: In javascript you can make an object containing array of menus and each menu object containing ref to sub menu, somehow need to add state of the menu in object too to collapse and open it. Once a menu is clicked, close all the other ones available in your array. A pretty manual vanilla javascript approach.